# Subselect to retrieve righthand-side of in-statement using CriteriaBuilder (JPA)

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am playing around with JPA and other Java EE 6 stuff, but now I am facing some problems with a types query using the criteria Builder.
The business case for my poc is a twitter clone, so I have users which has a list of subscribers and subscriptions and I got Tweets.

```
@Entity
public class Tweet {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private TwitterUser author;

    @ManyToOne
    private TwitterUser receiver;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
    private Date datetime; 

    private String message;
}


@Entity
public class TwitterUser {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String displayname;

    private String password;

    private String email;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date since;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TwitterUser> subscriptions;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subscriptions")
    private List<TwitterUser> subscribers;
}
```

The datamodel generated by JPA consists of 3 tables: Tweet, TwitterUser and TwitterUser_TwitterUser. Everything's fine so far. Basic queries do work well.

Now I want to select all Tweets for a timeline, what means all tweets of users, who are in the list of subscriptions of the current logged in user. I thought of a solution by using a subselect, so my sql would look like:

```
select * from TWEET where author_id in (
    select subscriptions_ID from TWITTERUSER_TWITTERUSER where subscribers_ID = ?loggedInUserId);
```

This query works well, but I have no idea how to write it down using the CriteriaBuilder and generics. I don't even get a compilable piece of code that could fail at some other point, because I am not sure what the type of the subquery should be.
I was searching through lots of examples now, but they are mostly just using raw-types or using the subquery for retrieving the element of the lefthand-side of the in-clause.

Maybe I miss the wood for trees but I am really perplexed here. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks again to you guys helping me. I finally managed to find a solution with your input and it looks as follows:

```
public List<Tweet> findAllForSubscriber(TwitterUser user) {
    // Select tweets
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tweet> cq = cb.createQuery(Tweet.class);
    Root<Tweet> tweet = cq.from(Tweet.class);
    cq.select(Tweet);

    // Select subscribers of user
    Subquery<Long> sq = cq.subquery(Long.class);
    Root<TwitterUser> twitterUser = sq.from(TwitterUser.class);
    Join<TwitterUser, TwitterUser> subscriptions = twitterUser.join(TwitterUser_.subscriptions);
    sq.select(subscriptions.get(TwitterUser_.id));
    sq.where(cb.equal(twitterUser, user));

    // Where authorId in list of subscribers
    cq.where(cb.in(tweet.get(Tweet_.author).get(TwitterUser_.id)).value(sq));

    //
    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

My drawbacks were:

- The Criteria API is just able to
  do a compare of objects within an
  equal() but not within a in()
  statement. But I did not get a
  helpful exception, all that was
  generated was a wrong query (eclipselink & derby) :(
- The in() statement
  takes the lefthand-side of the in
  statement, the value statement takes
  the list of possibilities, the
  wording confused me.
- I cannot simply access the ids
  of all subscriptions, I have to use a
  join. It's quite clear if you think
  about the table structure but I
  missed that when simply thinking of
  my objects.

P.S.: My solution totally misses to select the tweets of the user himself! ^^

Answer (score 3):

In JPQL, one way of expressing this would be something akin to the following:

```
SELECT
    tweet
FROM
    Tweet tweet JOIN tweet.author author
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 
               user 
         FROM 
                TwitterUser user JOIN user.subscriptions subscriber
         WHERE 
                user = :loggedinUser AND
                subscriber = author
    )
```

As Criterias following the JPQL model almost directly, maybe this gets you started.

Comment: Hi Arjan, thanks for your suggestions, it helped me rethink the problem and I found a quite easier solution, because I recognized I already got a list of all subscribers in my user object whose timeline I want to display. So thank you very much, but what finally drives me crazy is, that I did not found out how to formulate my query with the QueryBuilder. But well, I wasn't able to formulate yours either! ^^ So I think I have to work on my understanding of the expressions.

Comment: In general, JPQL (and with it Criterias) follow the spirit of SQL. But since JPQL does not expose the association (coupling) tables and does not allow you to join arbitrary columns in arbitrary tables, you do have to reverse your thinking about an approach at times.

Comment: For me the interesting thing was not to get a solution for my problem, I wanted to know how to do this using Criteria API, because I wanted to understand how to use it. Your approach of using a join was one of the facts that I missed and it helped me find the right solution, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar Criteria query example here,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#Subselect.2C_querying_all_of_a_ManyToMany_relationship

Comment: Thanks for the link, it finally switched from typed queries to untyped ones when it came to the interesting parts! But it showed me, that I simply used the in() statement wrong. So thanks again :)